# register_shutdown_function doesn't pass variables...?

Tags: php, session, include, footer, require

I've run into some difficulties with register_shutdown_function() in PHP. I have a header.php file which contains:

```
function shutdown(){
    require '/includes/footer.php';
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

//More code

extract($_SESSION);
```

$_SESSION contains an array called "user", containing things like the user ID and their username. I extract $_SESSION simply so I can use $user["id"] rather than $_SESSION["user"]["id"]. Then, in footer.php I have this code:

```
$_SESSION["user"]=$user;
```

to put the info back into the session, in case it's changed. But I'm getting the error:

**Notice**: Undefined variable: user in **C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\footer.php**

If I add print_r($user) to index.php then it prints it out perfectly. Similarly, if I remove the entire "shutdown" part from header.php, and then manually add:

```
require '/includes/footer.php';
```

to index.php then there's no issue.

So, if your register_shutdown_function() involves including a file (footer.php), *should you be able to use variables from index.php in footer.php*? If not, *why is there no variable called $user*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variable `$user` doesn't exist inside the [function's scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You should be doing what your question says and *passing it like a variable*:

```
extract($_SESSION);

function shutdown($user){
    echo $user;
    require '/includes/footer.php';
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $user);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize  `session_start()`, it is missing.  And use `isset()` to Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

```
  if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
       echo "Have value";
  }else{
       echo "There is no session value";
  }

register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $user);

 function shutdown($user){       
     // do your stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the variable as global within the shutdown function;

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    global $user;
    require '/includes/footer.php';
});
```